# How to close toggle slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, toggle, uislider

I have this jquery script:

```
<script>
var $root = $('html, body');
$('a').click(function() {
    var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
    }, 500, function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });
    return false;
});
// yeah let's do vanilla JS just for fun :P

var toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');
var slider = document.querySelector('.slider');

toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleSlider, false);

function toggleSlider(){
    if (slider.classList.contains('opened')) {
        slider.classList.remove('opened');
        slider.classList.add('closed');
    } else {
        slider.classList.remove('closed');
        slider.classList.add('opened');
    }
}



</script>
```

This link below toggles the box to open and close by sliding it down from the top.

```
<a href="#menu" id="toggle">Menu</a>
```

I want to create an additional link inside the opened box that just closes the box. What I tried to do is to rename `getElementsById` to `getElementsByClassName` and then update the `<a href="#menu" class="toggle">Menu</a>` so that I can use it twice but the scripts breaks.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you feel the need to do this in plain javascript when you've got jQuery loaded?

Should work in jQuery as such:

```
var $root = $('html, body');

$('a').click(function() {
    var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
    }, 500, function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });
    return false;
});

var $toggle = $('.toggle');
var $slider = $('.slider');

$toggle.on('click', function() {
    $slider.toggleClass('opened closed');
});
```

But if you insist on pure Javascript, did you remember to iterate through the list of links, since `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of nodes and the event listener has to be bound to each, not to the array, since that would throw an error. Try:

```
var toggle = document.getElementByClassName('toggle');
var slider = document.querySelector('.slider');

for(var i = 0; i < toggle.length; i++) {
    toggle[i].addEventListener('click', toggleSlider, false);
}
```

Also, if you have multiple sliders, you'll likely run into another issue of needing to iterate through them to modify their classes.